# React Higher-Order Components

Tags: reactjs

Hello I am trying to understand the concept of HOC

At the moment I have a hook to get width and height of the screen where I will use it in my grid layout:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';  

const getWindowDimensions = () => {
  const { innerWidth: width, innerHeight: height } = window;
  return {
    width,
    height
  };
};

const useWindowDimensions = () => {
  const [windowDimensions, setWindowDimensions] = useState(getWindowDimensions);

  useEffect(() => {
    function handleResize () {
      setWindowDimensions(getWindowDimensions())
    }

    window.addEventListener('resize', handleResize)
    return () => window.removeEventListener('resize', handleResize)
  }, []);

  return windowDimensions;
}

export default useWindowDimensions;
```

My question
As I need the width and height in all components would I better use the HOC?
or what should i do to make something more readable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you will need to make this into a HOC component, instead you have created a custom hook.

After doing that, you have multiple options.

1. Seen as window resizing is global, just store the new dimensions inside a global var.  This is the simplest option, and seen as window size is global storing this inside a global doesn't seem a bad idea.
2. Pass the dimensions down via props.  This has the advantage of not using any global's, but of course has the disadvantage of having to pass down props, and can be a pain if you have deep nested components, like most of us do.. :)
3. Use a context, although designed for Themes it can be used for passing anything down the render tree.  This also has the advantage of avoiding global, but also comes with another advantage passing down multiple routes, eg. If you was say using this for Theming, part of your page could use 1 theme, and the other another Theme.

Below is a simple example of just using a global, modifying to use props or context wouldn't be too hard.

```js
const {useState, useEffect} = React;

let gwin = {};

const getWindowDimensions = () => {
  const { innerWidth: width, innerHeight: height } = window;
  const r = {width, height};
  gwin = r;
  return r;
};

function Resizer(props) {
  const [windowDimensions, setWindowDimensions] =
    useState(getWindowDimensions());
  useEffect(() => {
    function handleResize () {
      setWindowDimensions(getWindowDimensions())
    }
    window.addEventListener('resize', handleResize)
    return () => window.removeEventListener('resize', handleResize)
  }, []);
  return props.children();
}

function ShowWindowSize1() {
  return <div>Window size = {gwin.width}, {gwin.height}</div>
}

function ShowWindowSize2() {
  return <div>
    Another Window size = <b>{gwin.width}, {gwin.height}</b>
  </div>
}

function Nested() {
  return <div style={{marginTop: "2rem",
  marginLeft: "2rem"}}>
    This is nested<br/>
    <ShowWindowSize2/>
    <ShowWindowSize1/>
  </div>
}


ReactDOM.render(<React.Fragment>
  <Resizer>{() =>
    <React.Fragment>
      <ShowWindowSize1/>
      <ShowWindowSize2/>
      <Nested/>
    </React.Fragment>}
  </Resizer>
</React.Fragment>, document.querySelector('#mount'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="mount"></div>
```

Comment: Hello, thanks
basically all the components i will use the width and height i will have to wrap in this file? Is there any possibility of me putting in index.js (main file where all my components would be?

Comment: maybe i solve this using the provider and context? Could you help me how I get this with context and provider?

Comment: Your global can just be stored inside a module so that it can be shared among all components.   You could alter to use a context, but you wouldn't gain anything more here.    If on the other hand you wanted to watch the size changes of a DIV / component then a context would make sense, as you could have multiple components to watch, and context would pass it's info down it's sub-tree's.  If you still want to use a context here, React Docs have some good info here -> https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Comment: Like what you said I think would make sense in this case or would not be necessary?

Basically I will define the widths of my component based on its size.
I will leave the width already set in variables like mobile = {menu: 240, content: 500} desktop = {
menu: 140
content: 800
}

and then according to the width size I would pass a variable to the components

Answer (score 0):

Since High order componenents have their use when we want the same functionality to be replicated over multiple components of our application. This helps in clean code and avoid duplicacy. You can modify the props as well in HOC and use it wherever you want in application. So, I recommend to use HOC in such a case

Comment: Could you give me an example of how I could create a higher order component to pass my useWindow?